# beego orm geospatial support

Tags: go, geospatial, beego

Does the Beego ORM support geospatial functions? I want to implement database queries with `"locations near me"` functionality.

If yes, I would like some guidance and if possible an example.

Comment: which database you're using for making geospatial queries?

Comment: @pramod I'm using MySQL, and rewriting existing app using go